# Python and SQLite: What will happen if I insert two rows with the same primary key?

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

Here is my table:

```
drop table if exists stocks;
create table stocks (
  stock_id integer primary key not null,
  stockname string not null
);
```

The Python code:

```
import sqlites3    
rows = [(1, 'IBM'),
          (2, 'MSOFT'),
          (1, 'GOOG'),
         ]
#c.executemany('insert into stocks values (?,?)', rows )
connection.commit()
```

In the `rows`, the 1st and 3rd have the same primary key.

What will happen if I do this? Will there be an exception? What can I do to catch the exception?

In reality, the `rows` are dynamic input, so I can not sort or edit the `rows` at first. And I am working with Flask 0.9 and Python 2.6 on Ubuntu 10.04.

Comment: Why don't you try it and see what happens?

Comment: `$ python` `>>> import sqlite3` `>>> (insert commands here)`

Comment: Also, since you're using Flask, try out [Flask-SQLAlchemy](http://packages.python.org/Flask-SQLAlchemy/).

Comment: @Blender I do not need Flask-SQLAlchemy. SQLite3 is enough for my program.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Already edited the typo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There will be an exception; `sqlite3.IntegrityError` will be raised:

```
>>> c.executemany('insert into stocks values (?,?)', [(1, 'IBM'), (2, 'MSOFT'), (1, 'GOOG')])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
sqlite3.IntegrityError: PRIMARY KEY must be unique
```

Any insertions before the exception is raised will have succeeded, so you want to call `connection.rollback()` when the exception occurs. Better still, use the connection as a [context manager](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html#using-the-connection-as-a-context-manager) to automatically roll back or commit:

```
try:
    with connection:
        c = connection.cursor()
        c.executemany('insert into stocks values (?,?)', rows)
    # insertion succeeded, `connection.commit()` is called automatically
except sqlite3.IntegrityError:
    # insertion failed, `connection.rollback()` is called automatically
```